# Use an array of x,y as indexes in an image array

Tags: numpy, numpy-indexing

I have an image:

```
>> img.shape
(720,1280)
```

I've identified a set of x,y coordinates I'd like to, where they are true, set a conformant image's value to 255.

Here is what I mean.  Forming the indexes are my `vals`:

```
>>> vals.shape
(720, 2)

>>> vals[0]
array([  0, 186]) # the x is 0, the y is 186, I'd like to set value at img[0][186]=255

>>> vals[719]
array([719, 207]) # the x is 719, the y is 207, I'd like to set value at img[719][207]=255
```

The first dimension of `vals` is redundant with `range(719)`.

I start by creating an image of the same shape as img:

```
>>> out = np.zeros_like(img)
>>> out.shape
(720, 1280)
```

But from here, my index into `out` seems not to work:

```
>>> out[vals] = 255
>>> out.shape
(720, 1280)
>>> out
array([[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
>>> out.min()
255
```

This makes /all/ `out` values 255, not only those where indexes of `out == vals`.

I'd expect:

```
>>> out[0][0]
0

>>> out[0][186]
255

>>> out[719][207]
255
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but is really ugly:

```
# out[(vals[:][:,0],vals[:][:,1])]=255
out[(vals[:,0],vals[:,1])]=255
```

Is there something better?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.random.rand(100, 200) # sample image, e.g. grayscaled.

where_to_change = [(20,10), (3, 4)]  # in (x, y)-fashion

#So, you need to set: `img[20, 10] = 1`, `img[3, 4]= 1` etc.... 

img[list(zip(*where))] = 1
```